# Getting indexPath of an object in FetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data

I am creating a table view controller for an app that manages position assignments for a team. The sections with headers for defense, center, and offense for example will have names in them if a position Entity exists with that positionProperty. If that person is removed though through swiping, they become an alternate entity with same positionProperty.

I am trying to have the alternates for each position display when the edit button is tapped. Much like extra contact details appear when you edit a contact in the contacts app.

I have a fetchedResultsController returning the parent entity for alts/positions keyed by the positionProperty to define sections. (This may be the wrong way to do this... I am new to Core Data).

In setEditing:WithAnimation I have done the following. Attempting to search my fetched results and if any objects are of type Alternate, display that row. So in the enumeration, if it is type alternate I tried to call IndexPathForObjects:alt. This just returned nil...

```
    if(editing){

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        for (MCAlternate *alt in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
            if ([alt isKindOfClass:[MCAlternate class]]) {
                NSLog(@"The alternate is: %@", alt);

                // This is where the error is trying to get indexPathForObject
                NSIndexPath *index = [fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:alt];
               [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            }
        }
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
```

I have checked if the object exists in the results. It does. I have also tried called the getindexpath in a place with the object was just created by calling objectAtIndexPath and it still came back nil.

any suggestions are appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are not using your fetched results controller as it is foreseen. Your frc should fetch all the data to populate the table view.

You can still achieve the dynamic table content by tweaking your table view `datasource` methods. Suppose you are fetching the entity "Position" and the position object in question has a to-many attribute of entity "MCAlternate" called "alternates". You would then expand a certain section as follows:

```
-(void)expandSectionForPosition:(Position *)position {
    int row = 0;
    int section = [[frc indexPathForObject:position] section];
    for (MCAlternate *alt in position.alternates) {
         // update your datasource - e.g. by marking the position as 
         // "expanded"; make sure your numberOfRowsInSection reflects that

         [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath 
           indexPathForRow:i++ inSection:section]] 
           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
```

Your class check is not logical - you are casting as MCAlternate in the for loop anyway. Your call or getting the index path fails, because you typically do not have a separate fetched results controller.

Comment: I don't know why i didn't think of having a to-many reltionship from the position to alternate! I knew my model was not ideal but couldn't figure out the best way. I will go with that.

As for my check for MCAlternate... the fast enum was returning everything (both positions and alts) that was in the FRC. I thought that was strange to but I figured a class check would solve it. 

Thanks for the CD model suggestion.